# Reload apache within a python script on linux

Tags: python-3.x, linux, apache

Hi I am trying to create a python file that reloads apache2 the code of this file is:

```
import os

os.system("service apache2 reload")
```

When I use the command in the terminal everything works fine but when I run the python script I got this error:

```
Job for apache2.service failed.
See "systemctl status apache2.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
```

so I checked the `journalctl` and got this:

```
nov 29 13:50:19 gerrietech apachectl[37415]: Action 'graceful' failed.
nov 29 13:50:19 gerrietech apachectl[37415]: The Apache error log may have more information.
```

end this comes out of the error log:

```
AH00558: apache2: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 192.168.50.183. Set the 'ServerName' directive globally to suppress this message
[Mon Nov 29 13:37:35.533656 2021] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 36741] AH00163: Apache/2.4.46 (Ubuntu) OpenSSL/1.1.1f configured -- resuming normal operations
[Mon Nov 29 13:37:35.533672 2021] [core:notice] [pid 36741] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
[Mon Nov 29 13:38:23.180736 2021] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 36741] AH00169: caught SIGTERM, shutting down
[Mon Nov 29 13:38:45.809351 2021] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 37219] AH00163: Apache/2.4.46 (Ubuntu) OpenSSL/1.1.1f configured -- resuming normal operations
[Mon Nov 29 13:38:45.809422 2021] [core:notice] [pid 37219] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
```

How do i fix this?

Comment: May be try with `apachectl` instead of `systemd`.

Comment: Have you added the 'ServerName' directive to the conf file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After i used /etc/init.d/apache2 reload instead of service apache2 restarti dont get any errors and the script does what it is supposed to do

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).